# How can I statically analyze php scripts to detect global variable usage

Tags: php, global-variables, static-analysis, tokenize

I would like to process a folder and count the number of times each global variable
is used.  I do have a list of the globals, but it would be way cooler if the script
detected and output both the name and number of instances.  This cannot be done at
runtime though.

I suspect that it is possible to use token_get_all within PHP to do so, but
the documentation is rather sparse...

Answer (score 3):

This is a trivial FSM I've just written to demonstrate how to extract all the global variables from the code:

```
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php function a() { global $b,

$c; } ?>');


$state = 0; // 1 for processing T_GLOBAL, 0 otherwise
$global_vars = array();
foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    if (!is_array($token)) {
        if ($state == 1 && $token == ';') {
            $state = 0;
        }

        continue;
    }

    if ($token[0] == T_GLOBAL) {
        $state = 1;
        continue;
    }

    if ($state == 1 && $token[0] == T_VARIABLE) {
        $global_vars[] = $token[1];
        continue;
    }
}

var_dump($global_vars);
```

It's quite easy to add counter for each variable.